# Xquery the function parse-xml() produces an error on &amp;?

Tags: xpath, xquery, exist-db

As XML content in an HTTP POST request, I receive the following which I process in Xquery 3.1 (eXist-db 5.2):

```
<request id="foo">
     <p>The is a description with a line break&lt;br/&gt;and another linebreak&lt;br/&gt;and
            here is an ampersand&amp;.</p>
<request>
```

My objective is to take the node `<p>` and insert it into a TEI file in eXist-db. If I just insert the fragment as-is, no errors are thrown.

However I need to transform any instances of string `&lt;br/&gt;` into element `<lb/>` before adding it to the TEI document. I try that with `fn:parse-xml`.

Applying the following, however, throws an error on `&amp`...which surprises me:

```
let $xml := <request id="foo">
                 <p>The is a description with a line break&lt;br/&gt;and 
                    another linebreak&lt;br/&gt;and here is an ampersand&amp;.</p>
           <request>
let $newxml := <p>{replace($xml//p/text(),"&lt;br/&gt;","&lt;lb/&gt;")}</p>
return <p>{fn:parse-xml($newxml)}</p>
```

error:

```
Description: err:FODC0006 String passed to fn:parse-xml is not a well-formed XML document.: Document is not valid.
Fatal : The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
```

If I remove `&amp;` the fragment parses just fine. Why is this producing an error if it is legal XML? How can I achieve the needed result?

Many thanks in advance.

ps. I am open to both Xquery and XSLT solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue is the HTML entities. It would work with numeric entities (i.e. `&#60;` instead of `&lt;` and `&#62;` instead of `&gt;`), but the XML parser doesn't know about HTML character entities.

Use[`util:parse-html()`](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/util&location=java:org.exist.xquery.functions.util.UtilModule&details=true#parse-html.1) instead of `fn:parse-xml()`.

```
let $xml := <request id="foo">
                  <p>The is a description with a line break&lt;br/&gt;and 
                    another linebreak&lt;br/&gt;and here is an ampersand&amp;.</p>
           </request>
return <p>{util:parse-html($xml/p/text())/HTML/BODY/node()}</p>
```

Comment: This has the merit of working, although it wraps everything in HTML body, etc. But from there I can transform to final TEI XML at least!

Comment: Right, you can XPath into it to select just the markup. I'll update the answer.